# Soup.find_all is only returning Some of the results in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get all of the urls for thumbnails from my webpage that have the class = "thumb", but soup.find_all is only printing the most recent 22 or so.

Here is the Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://rayleighev.deviantart.com/gallery/44021661/Reddit")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a", {'class' : "thumb"})
for link in links:
    print(link.get("href"))
```

Comment: As far as I can see there are 24 such links on the linked page. So I guess the code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to ask about *following the pagination* and grabbing all the links in a list. Here is the implementation of that idea - use the `offset` parameter and grab links until there are no more links present incrementing the `offset` by 24 (number of links per page):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


offset = 0
links = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    while True:
        r = session.get("http://rayleighev.deviantart.com/gallery/44021661/Reddit?offset=%d" % offset)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        new_links = [link["href"] for link in soup.find_all("a", {'class': "thumb"})]

        # no more links - break the loop
        if not new_links:
            break

        links.extend(new_links)
        print(len(links))
        offset += 24

print(links)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you that worked. And not to be a bother, but what modifications would be needed to grab all the 24 links for only one page in the gallery and put them into a list?

Comment: @Rayleighev you can just get rid of the loop and leave `offset` as `0` or just use the `http://rayleighev.deviantart.com/gallery/44021661/Reddit` url without an offset. Hope that helps.